# Can't get azure javascript push to work on client or server

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

Steps:

1. Create Azure mobile app with node.js backend. (server)
2. Create NotificationHub associated to the new mobile app. (server)
3. Create WinJS App (Universal Windows) in Visual Studio (client)
4. Associate app with App Store VS > Project > Store > Associate App with Store (client)
5. Include Mobile Services MobileServices.Web.js to connect with mobile services backend (client)
6. Connect to mobile service backend (client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://.azurewebsites.net') (client)

I am having a problem trying to get the tags for push notification hub that is tied to my azure mobile service node.js backend.

I am following this blog post:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/writingdata_services/2016/04/14/adding-push-notification-tags-from-a-node-js-backend/

on how to create tags on the node.js backend.

When I call the createTags API I am presuming the tag is being created because there is no  error being returned.

But when I call getTags API my error routine is firing with the error

```
An error occurred when retrieving installation

Error: 404 - Installation not found.TrackingId:0615f100-35fe-496e-b63d-53d39d7e1cf9_G1,TimeStamp:10/27/2016 9:46:25 PM
```

I can't figure out why I am getting this error?

Can anyone see what I am missing or need to do to fix this problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

createTags.js

```
module.exports = {
    "post": function (req, res, next) {
        // Get the notification hub used by the mobile app.
        var push = req.azureMobile.push;

        console.log('create tags installationId ' + req.body.installationId);
        console.log('tags ' + req.body.tags.toString());

        // Validate for and block any SID tags.
        for (var i = 0; i < req.body.tags.length; i++) {
            if (req.body.tags[i].search("sid:") !== -1) {
                    res.status(403)
                    .send("You cannot set '" + req.body.tags[i] + "' as a tag.");
                    return;
            }
        }

        // Define an update tags operation.
        var updateOperation = [{
            "op": "add",
            "path": "/tags",
            "value": req.body.tags.toString()
        }];     

        // Update the installation to add the new tags.
        push.patchInstallation(req.body.installationId, updateOperation, function(error, response){
            if(error){
                console.log('An error occurred when adding tags\n\n' + error);
                res.status(error.statusCode).send(error.detail);
            }
            else res.status(200).send();
        });
    }
};
```

getTags.js

```
module.exports = {
    "post": function (req, res, next) {
        // Get the notification hub used by the mobile app.
        var push = req.azureMobile.push;

        console.log('getting tags');

        if (typeof req.body.installationId !== "undefined"){
            push.getInstallation(req.body.installationId, function (error, response) {
                if (error) {
                    console.log('An error occurred when retrieving installation\n\n' + error);
                    res.status(error.statusCode).send(error);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("got installation " + req.body.installationId + '\n\n' + JSON.stringify(response));

                    res.status(200).send(response);
                }
            });
        }
        else res.status(200).send();
    }
};
```

main.js - here is my winjs app to create the tag and then check that it was created

```
client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://<sitename>.azurewebsites.net');

client.invokeApi("createTags", {
    body: {
        installationId: client.push.installationId,
        tags: ['public']
    },
    method: "post"
}).then(function (result) {
    client.invokeApi("getTags", {
        body: {
            installationId: client.push.installationId,
        },
        method: "post"
    }).then(function (result) {
        WinJS.log(result);
        completeDispatcher();
    }, function (error) {
        WinJS.log(error);
        completeDispatcher();
    });
}, function (error) {
    WinJS.log(error);
    completeDispatcher();
});
```

Update now trying to use this to create a channel first.  Then register a listener.

```
// Request a push notification channel.
Windows.Networking.PushNotifications
    .PushNotificationChannelManager
    .createPushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync()
    .then(function (newChannel) {
        channel = newChannel;

        // Register for notifications using the new channel
        Machine.Client.push.register('wns', channel.uri, ['public']).done(function (error, response) {
            // store the channel
            channel.removeEventListener("pushnotificationreceived", pushNotificationReceivedHandler);
            channel.addEventListener("pushnotificationreceived", pushNotificationReceivedHandler);
            completeDispatcher();
        });
    }, function (error) {
        var dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(error, "Error");
        dialog.showAsync().then(function () {
            completeDispatcher();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For these type of issues, usually going through [Notification Hubs Diagnosis guidelines](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-push-notification-fixer/) should give you an idea where the problem is. The 'Verify registrations' section there might be helpful in your case.

If nothing there helps, could update the question with what you've learned?

Comment: Hi Nikita,

I am having difficulty finding any documentation on how to send a push notification to a javascript client from a node.js mobile service app.

I have created a windows uwp app using winjs.  I have authenticated the user using client connection but i can't send a simple push.

Do I still need to create a channelUri ?  Does notificationhub use those still?

Comment: I can feel there is a piece of the puzzle missing I just can't figure it out.

Comment: [Send push notifications to Chrome apps with Azure Notification Hubs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-chrome-push-notifications-get-started) seems to be talking about a JS client, see if you can re-use some of the code/ideas from there. For the `channelUri` -- you don't need to 'create' it, Windows will return it for you and then you need to register it with NH so that it can push to the device. See a [Windows sample](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-wns-push-notification/)

Comment: what shud the call to the server (createTags.js) look like without channelUri?  That part I am confused about.  And the return value and how to use that for my "pushReceived" handler???  Thankyou for your help by the way.  I've been at this for two weeks now since I had to update my mobile service app.  Microsoft didnt leave any documention for people using winjs UWP apps and how we can transition over easily.

Comment: In your example `createTags.js` patches an existing installation. So it means that the corresponding `channelUri` has already been installed/registered previously. So you don't need to provide it there anymore. Not sure what you mean by `pushReceived` handler, I couldn't find that in your code.

Comment: I haven't registered a channelUri though?

So i guess that is the bit that I am missing.

I have just finished doing this tutuorial https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-push/ and noticed that there is this line var hub = new NotificationHub("<hubname>", "Endpoint=sb://...");

then the registerNativeAsync(channel.Uri) is invoked.  How do I do this bit but in javascript instead of c#?

Comment: For an example of how to register a device from JS see `sendNHRegistrationRequest` function from the [Send push notifications to Chrome apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-chrome-push-notifications-get-started) I mentioned. But beware that the payload they are using is for GCM, not Windows. You'd need something like [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495628.aspx) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28904225/182371) to make it work in Windows using `WindowsRegistrationDescription`.